# combining 2 mysql queries into 1

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am having trouble creating a single mysql query for what i am trying to do here.

first off, i will show you the table structures and fields of the tables i am using for this particular query:

```
users:
- id
- name
- photo_name
- photo_ext

user_attacks:
- id
- level

user_news_feed:
- id
- id_user
- id_status
- id_attack
- id_profile
- id_wall
- the_date

user_status:
- id
- status

user_wall:
- id
- id_user
- id_poster
- post
```

whenever the user posts an attack, or status update, updates their profile, or posts on someones wall, it inserts the relevant data into its respective table and also inserts a new row into the user_news_feed table.

now, what i want to do is select the last 10 news feed items from the database. these news feed items need to grab relevant data from other tables as long as their value is not 0. so if the news feed is for a status update, the id_status would be the id of the status update in the user_status table, and the "status" would be the data needing to be selected via a left join. hope that makes sense.

heres my first mysql query:

```
$sql = mysql_query("select n.id_user, n.id_status, n.id_attack, n.id_profile, n.id_wall, n.the_date, u.id, u.name, u.photo_name, u.photo_ext, s.status
                    from `user_news_feed` as n
                    left join `users` u on (u.id = n.id_user)
                    left join `user_status` s on (s.id = n.id_status)
                    where n.id_user='".$_GET['id']."'
                    order by n.id desc
                    limit 10
                    ");
```

now this works great, except for 1 problem. as you can see the user_wall table contains the id's for 2 different users. id_user is the user id the post is being made for, and id_poster is the user id of the person making that wall post. if the user makes a wall post on his/her own wall, it is inserted into the database as a status update into the user_status table instead.

so i have a conditional statement within the while loop for the first query, which has another sql query within it. here is the whole code for the while loop and second sql query:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    if ($row['id_wall'] != 0)
    {
        $sql_u = mysql_query("select u.id, u.name, u.photo_name, u.photo_ext, w.post
                              from `user_wall` as w
                              left join `users` u on (u.id = w.id_poster)
                              where w.id='".$row['id_wall']."'
                              ");

        while ($row_u = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_u))
        {
            $row['photo_name'] = $row_u['photo_name'];
            $row['photo_ext'] = $row_u['photo_ext'];
            $row['id_user'] = $row_u['id'];
            $row['name'] = $row_u['name'];
            $content = $row_u['post'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ($row['id_status'] != 0)
            $content = $row['status'];
        else if ($row['id_attack'] != 0)
            $content = '<i>Had an attack</i>';
        else if ($row['id_profile'] != 0)
            $content = '<i>Updated profile</i>';
    }

    echo '<li'.(($count == $total_count) ? ' class="last"' : '').'>';

    echo '<img src="images/profile/'.$row['photo_name'].'_thumb.'.$row['photo_ext'].'" alt="" />';

    echo '<div class="content">';
    echo '<b><a href="profile.php?id='.$row['id_user'].'">'.$row['name'].'</a></b>';
    echo '<span>'.$content.'</span>';
    echo '<small>'.date('F j, Y \a\t g:ia', $row['the_date']).'</small>';
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div style="clear: both;"></div>';

    echo '</li>';
}
```

i hope what i am trying to do here makes sense. so basically i want to have both sql queries ($sql, and $sql_u) combined into a single query so i do not have to query the database every single time when the user_news_feed item is a wall post.

any help would be greatly appreciated and i apologise if this is confusing.

Comment: Note you have an SQL injection vulnerability with `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: it is checked above with an escaped query. if a user is not found with $_GET['id'] (escaped of course) it throws a "profile not found" page and the queries in the OP are not executed at all.

Comment: OK - that was not visible to us, of course, but I'm glad to hear you head off the trouble before it gets to this code.

Comment: @scarhand i have no idea what you mean by escaped query. There is no such thing. This query however is a clear fail and well get you pwnd. Please seach so for "SQL-injection" and learn to use mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: $sql = mysql_query("select u.*, c.name as country_name
     from `users` as u
     left join `countries` c on (c.id = u.id_country)
     where u.id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."'");

if (mysql_num_rows($sql) == 0)
{
 die('profile not found');
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n.id_user, n.id_status, n.id_attack, n.id_profile, n.id_wall, n.the_date,
       u.id, u.name, u.photo_name, u.photo_ext, s.status,
       w.id AS wall_user_id, w.name AS wall_user_name,
       w.photo_name AS wall_user_photo_name,
       w.photo_ext  AS wall_user_photo_ext,
       w.post
  FROM user_news_feed AS n
  LEFT JOIN users AS u ON (u.id = n.id_user)
  LEFT JOIN user_status s ON (s.id = n.id_status)
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT a.id AS id_wall, b.id, b.name, b.photo_name, b.photo_ext, a.post
               FROM user_wall  AS a
               LEFT JOIN users AS b ON (b.id = a.id_poster)
            ) AS w ON w.id_wall = n.id_wall
 WHERE n.id_user = ?
 ORDER BY n.id desc
 LIMIT 10
```

The '?' is a placeholder where you can provide the value of `$_GET['id']`.

Basically, this adds an extra outer join, to the main query (and some extra columns, which will be NULL if the news feed event is not a wall posting), but the outer join is itself the result of an outer join.

Comment: awesome! exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 0):

Back again ;)

Anyway, forget about merging the queries in my opinion.

What you should do instead is to do the first query, loop through all the results and store all "id_wall"s in a separate array... then rather than doing a separate query per "id_wall" you do this:

```
$wallids = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{ 
    $wallids[] = $row['id_wall'];
    // also store the row wherever you want
}

$sql_u = mysql_query("select u.id, u.name, u.photo_name, u.photo_ext, w.post    
                      from `user_wall` as w    
                      left join `users` u on (u.id = w.id_poster)    
                      where w.id IN ('".implode(',', $wallids) ."')    
                      ");
```

$wallids being an array with all the "id_wall"s. So now you have a total of 2 queries.

Comment: i was thinking about using an array...was just wondering if i could pull this off with 1 query though...

Comment: I don't see why you would want to do it with 1 query, there is nothing inherently better about just using 1 query... it can sometimes even be faster to use 2 queries. Especially with queries like this, it is very possible that you'll end up with hugely redundant data soaking up bandwidth... or very suboptimal MySQL behavior. Since the user data will be duplicated in every for every wall post.

Comment: -1 doing it this way will be much slower because you are kill any chance of using an index and replacing it with one of sql's slowest operators 'IN' a clear fail (typing on the phone sorry for the slowness)

Comment: @Johan That is definately not true, I often use the IN queries rather than do 1:M joins (unless I have to)... it can often be on the order of 50-200% faster when querying thousands of records. And of course you can still use indexes. I've even used IN with 100.000 records and it was considerably faster than what joins could do.

Comment: That's because you either have the wrong indexes or writing the wrong query. It's hard to make statements without a definite example, but if you have one of those slow queries, please feel free to post the query + an "explain select" and then we can discuss facts.

Comment: @Johan no there is nothing wrong. A basic join between a lot of users and their posts... was considerable slower than selecting users and then selecting their posts with IN to produce identical results. All queries are on the PK. And the result is easier to process as you don't have to extract unique users in some quirky way. It's at the work though so I have no data to present.

Comment: @Johan logged in remotely and performed the queries ... http://pastebin.com/VJUaFvyf ... yes, it's a lot of rows, yes the ratio is very off... but still 2.0s vs 0.2s ... and I know for a fact that IN scales equally well up and beyond 10.000 emails, even with fewer recipients per email. So please explain how IN is the slowest operator and how I'm wrong.

Comment: @andreas will be happy to but i'm traveling and on the iphone.  Not a great sql profiling tool. Will be happy to look at it when a keyboard presents itself

Comment: @Johan Another situation that appeared at work was to go through 100.000+ records in batches and do some work on each of them. Selecting with LIMIT and OFFSET performs horribly as the offset increases, while selecting all 100.000 IDs first and then selecting 1.000 IDs with IN at a time performed many times faster, on the order of 10x or something like that.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3148/discussion-between-johan-and-andreas)